# Plot contours from one graph into another in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, contour

I have a data file with four columns X Y Z1 Z2 and I want to create a seperate color plot for each Z but plot contour lines from the first one also into the second one.

First I create a plot for Z1 and the contour file with

```
set terminal "pdfcairo" enhanced dashed size 5,5
set output "Output1.pdf"

set pm3d 
unset surface
set view map
set contour
set cntrparam levels discrete 1.45,1.50

set table 'DATAFILE.contourZ1'
splot 'DATAFILE' using 1:2:3 notitle with lines
unset table

splot 'DATAFILE' using 1:2:3 notitle with lines

unset output
```

This gives me the color plot with two contour lines along Z1=1.45 and 1.50. So far so good. To load the contours into the second plot I tried

```
splot 'DATAFILE' using 1:2:4 notitle with lines,\
    'DATAFILE.contourZ1' using 1:2:3 notitle with lines
```

but this only gives me the colorplot for Z2 without any contour lines.

Does anyone know, how I can accomplish this? If it's not possible in such an easy way as I have tried, I'm open for other ways, too :)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `unset pm3d` before saving the table file so that you get a file with only the contour-line points.

Then if you want to plot pm3d **and** lines you might want to use `set pm3d explicit` and a `splot "contour.txt" with lines, "data" with pm3d`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it's not working. I'm getting the message `warning: Can't use pm3d for 2d plots` and the resulting plot shows the contour lines only.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much. For anyone else who wants to try this I would suggest switching the order of "contour.txt" and "data" to make sure the contours are in front of the color plot.